# Sliding jquery tabbed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabbed

Could somebody please help me to alter the tabbed content code to fade and slide the tabbed content in and out as the tabs change please.

I'm using **[this script](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGBmYd)**.

And the code in the header bit:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current')
})
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Well I got a working script with a creative idea.
http://codepen.io/hamzadhamiya/pen/vBubl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').fadeOut(100).removeClass('current');

        $(this).fadeIn(1000).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).fadeIn(1000).addClass('current');
 })
```

**UPDATE**

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwePEo)**

To SlideUp and SlideDown try as below:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').slideUp("slow",function(){
              $(this).removeClass('current');
        });
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).slideDown("slow",function(){
              $(this).addClass('current');
        });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help friend, I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: Out of curiosity , would you be able to help me with assigning each button with a specific icon and assign "current state" to the icons.

I'm trying to achieve a different colour icon on "currently selected estate"